# How to print original compile time error in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, compilation, ide

I am trying to run following program to check compile time error:

```
import java.io.*;
class Test
{
public static void main(String... args)
{

int x="sachin";

}

}
```

1) While running above program in notepad using cmd, following compile time error will be generated:

```
Test.java:7: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to 
int
int x="sachin";
```

2) While running above program in eclipse ide, following compile time error will be generated:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

    at JavaDemo/com.vis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
```

So the error coming at the (1) case is actual error produced by java compiler in command prompt and error coming at the (2) case is  also produced by java compiler but in a modified way by eclipse ide.

So now my question is how can i get same error in eclipse ide without any modification by ide?? I hope I made you guys understood of my point. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different things: 
1) compile message error;
2) running error message. 
Eclipse compile code in background and show the errors in view "Problems" or in red icon in the editor. In your second example you are running a code with a compile error. So jvm show another message type.

Comment: If there are errors at compile time then error is shown by red line. And if you read that compile time error showing by red line that is not exactly same as of compile time error when we run by command prompt. How can i see same compile time error in eclipse which is shown by compiling through command prompt?

Comment: Eclipse has its own Java Compiler, which can also be run on the command line, which has slightly different error messages than `javac` (_"incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int"_ vs. _"Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int"_). By default, the Eclipse compiler works incrementally on save and allows to execute code even if not everything has been compiled because of compile errors. That's what the first line says (_"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:"_): you are executing code that is missing due to the following compile error.

Comment: @howlger, thank for quick and effective response. Is there any way we can force eclipse to show the same exact compile time error what we see at command prompt while running through notepad.

Comment: @VishambarPandey Eclipse is bound to its own compiler, with more warnings and more detailed warnings than `javac` (e.g. null analysis, dead code,...). Therefore it would make more sense to run the Eclipse compiler on the command line than to run `javac` within Eclipse. In Eclipse you can trigger `javac` by Eclipse via an Ant, a Maven, a Gradel launch configuration or also directly which will prompt the `javac` output in the _Console_ view, but does not show the errors as problem markers inside the Java editors. Both, `javac` and the Eclipse compiler implements the Java Language Specification.